# Angular Add Control with Name instead of iterator in FormArray using foreach

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In FormArray I need Features as formarry with following structure (I am not able to add names of respective control by default its taking as iterator 1,2,3,4) where as it should work like addControl.

**Expected**

```
Features: {
  MyCars: false,
  YourCars: false,
  ThereCar: false,
  WhereCar: false,
}
```

Declaration of form

```
public addStorageFacility(): FormGroup {
  return this.formBuilder.group({
  Features: this.formBuilder.array([])
})
```

HTML Code

```
 <div class="row g-0 features" formArrayName="Features">
            <label>{{'facility.features' | translate}}</label>
            <div *ngFor="let unit of getFeaturesDetailsControls(); let i = index"
             class="col featureslist">
            <mat-checkbox [formControlName]="unit.value">
              {{unit.value}}
            </mat-checkbox>
            </div>
        </div>
```

ts function to get featuredetails

```
public getFeaturesDetailsControls() {
 // console.log(this.storageFacilityDetailsForm.get('Features'));
  return (this.storageFacilityDetailsForm.get('Features') as FormArray).controls;
}
```

Feature list is array which needs to be iterated

```
const featureList = this.featureList;
const controlVal = this.storageFacilityDetailsForm.controls['Features'] as FormArray;
featureList.forEach((control,i) => {
        controlVal.push(this.formBuilder.control(control.description));
      })
```

**Output received**

[image]

Comment: Maybe a formArray is not the best choice? Why not add normal controls to a group instead?

Comment: Facility names are dynamic and I will get array from server which needs iterating for control names.

Comment: @MikeOne you are correct. did same trick with formGroup and it worked.